# how to build own simple router in golang?

Tags: go, router, httpserver

I am building own router in golang to understand logic , however I am getting 404 error not found normally, i able to running to server but I wrote function in **hello** name, it is not running. what could reason for this ?

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var Session *http.Server
var r Router

func Run(port string) {
    Session = &http.Server{
        Addr:           port,
        Handler:        &r,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
    log.Fatal(Session.ListenAndServe())
}

type Handle func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)

type Router struct {
    mux map[string]Handle
}

func newRouter() *Router {
    return &Router{
        mux: make(map[string]Handle),
    }
}

func (r *Router) Add(path string, handle Handle) {
    r.mux[path] = handle
}

func GetHeader(url string) string {
    sl := strings.Split(url, "/")
    return fmt.Sprintf("/%s", sl[1])
}

func (rt *Router) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    head := GetHeader(r.URL.Path)
    h, ok := rt.mux[head]
    if ok {
        h(w, r)
        return
    }
    http.NotFound(w, r)
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", "hello world")
}

func main() {
    r := newRouter()
    r.Add("/hello", hello)
    Run(":8080")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main function, by using the `:=` notation, is declaring and initialising a new local variable called r, whose scope is different from the global variable you have on the top of your listing.

This means that the `r` variable that you're adding the handler to, is not the global one that you're trying to assign to the `Http.Server` struct, therefore your `ServeHTTP` will not find any mapping at all into its own receiver `r`.

A solution is to declare the `r Router` as a pointer to a `Router`, like this:

```
var r *Router
```

and in your handler, you can pass directly the pointer without any dereference:

```
Session = &http.Server{
        Addr:           port,
        Handler:        r,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
```

Of course, remember to initialise the variable by assigning the pointer value and not declaring a new local one:

```
func main() {
    r = newRouter()
    r.Add("/hello", hello)
    Run(":8080")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have global variable `var r Router` but inside your `func main()` you create another, local one and path happens to be added only to it:

```
 func main() {
        r := newRouter()
        r.Add("/hello", hello)
        Run(":8080")
    }
```

simply adjust

```
var r =&Router{}

func Run(port string) {
    Session = &http.Server{
        Addr:           port,
        Handler:        r,
        ReadTimeout:    10 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
        MaxHeaderBytes: 1 << 20,
    }
    log.Fatal(Session.ListenAndServe())
}
func main() {
    r = newRouter()
    r.Add("/hello", hello)
    Run(":8080")
}
```